# Google Sheets - Copy row script copies entire sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Obviously I have a small error as the code used copies the entire page, not just the row.

What I am trying to achieve is whenever "Green" is entered in Column 4 on Sheet "Jobs", the script copies that row to the next empty row on Sheet "Fleet"

I was also wondering if there is a way to possibly shade the copied row as a confirmation it has been copied to the "Fleet Sheet"

Here is the code so far:

```
function onEdit() 
{
var sheetNameToWatch = "Jobs";
var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
var valueToWatch = "Green";
var sheetNameToCopyTheRowTo = "Fleet";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == 
columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch)
{
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToCopyTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 
sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
}
```

Here is the link to an open copy of the spreadsheet (no important data so feel free to edit):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/138PBXEsKdhhxkKNTCGaFaWgrOTQcnN3tPWHO8pp7GMg/edit#gid=610845771

Comment: Show off your research efforts.

Comment: `sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);`.  This line starts at row 2, column 1, and collects through to the last row and last column, then copies to the target sheet.  `.getRange(start row, start col, # rows, # cols)`.  This is your problem.